# how to update a component from another component in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to update my custom header component from this page. basically this page is my cart page. and custom header returns total no of cart item.but when first time I open cart page it shows correct data.but after add to cart some product when I go-cart page custom header not updated. but the cart page updated correctly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image, BackHandler, AsyncStorage, FlatList, ScrollView, ImageBackground, TextInput, Alert, Modal } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import {
    responsiveHeight,
    responsiveWidth,
    responsiveFontSize
} from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
import { Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import { TouchableOpacity, TapGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import AnimatedLoader from "react-native-animated-loader";
import AwesomeAlert from 'react-native-awesome-alerts';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import CustomHeader from '../../CustomeHeader';

import { IMAGE } from '../../../constants/Image';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const BannerWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 20;
const BannerHeight = 150;
const Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;

class MyCartScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coupon: '',
            count: 0,
            productlist: '',
            isLoading: false,
            showModal: false,
            push_array: '',
            user_auth: '',
            data_emty_check: false,
            showAlert1: false,
            Msg: '',
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        this.getCartItem();
    }

    getCartItem = async () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_hash', (err, res) => {
            AsyncStorage.getItem('cartsession', (err, cartres) => {
                //console.log(cartres + 'dfdfdf');
                let newProduct = JSON.parse(cartres);
                if (newProduct == '' || newProduct == null) {
                    //console.log(res);
                    fetch('https://swissmade.direct/wp-json/swissmade/cart/items', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            auth_hash: JSON.parse(res)
                        }),
                    })

                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((resp) => {
                            //console.log(resp);

                            if (resp.error == false) {

                                AsyncStorage.setItem('cartsession', JSON.stringify(resp.items));
                                this.setState({
                                    productlist: resp.items,
                                    isLoading: false
                                });
                                //console.log(this.state.productlist)


                            } else {
                                this.setState({
                                    isLoading: false,
                                    data_emty_check: true
                                });
                                
                                //this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                            }

                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            alert("Something Went Wronggg");
                        });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        productlist: JSON.parse(cartres),
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                }

            });

        });
    }

 

    _onNavigationStateChange(webViewState) {
        //console.log(webViewState);

    }

    renderCategory = ({ item, index }) => {
        const entities = new Entities();
        const price = (item.price * item.qty).toFixed(2);
        const p_id = item.p_id;
        var img = { 'uri': item.thumbnail };
        //this.setState({ [`count${index}`]: item.qty })
        return (
            <View style={styles.childdiv} elevation={5}>
                <Image source={img} style={styles.moreImg} />
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', padding: 5, width: responsiveWidth(55), justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.userNmae}>{entities.decode(item.title)} </Text>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={styles.price}>{entities.decode(item.currency)} {price}</Text>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.decrement(index, p_id)}>
                                <Image source={require('../../../../assets/minus.png')}
                                    style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginTop: 10 }} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 10, color: 'black' }}>{item.qty}</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.increment(index, p_id)}>
                                <Image source={require('../../../../assets/plus.png')}
                                    style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginTop: 10 }} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        {/* <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.8)', height: 20, width: 20, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 2, color: 'white' }}>{item.qty}</Text>
                        </View> */}
                    </View>
                </View>
                <FontAwesomeIcon style={styles.navItemStyle} name="trash" size={22} onPress={() => this.trashItem(item.p_id, item.v_id, item.qty)} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    // showAlert1 = () => {
    //     this.setState({
    //         showAlert1: true
    //     });
    // };

    // hideAlert = () => {
    //     this.setState({
    //         showAlert1: false
    //     });
    // };

    render() {
        //const { showAlert1 } = this.state;
       // const { Msg } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <CustomHeader title="My Cart" navigation={this.props.navigation} />

                <Modal
                    visible={this.state.showModal}
                    onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
                >
                    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: "50%", right: 0, left: 0 }}>

                    </View>
                    <WebView
                        source={{ uri: `https://swissmade.direct/?api_addtocart=1&items=${this.state.push_array}&user=${this.state.expire_time}` }}
                        onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}

                    />
                </Modal>
                {
                    this.state.data_emty_check ?
                        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', margin: 5, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Image
                                source={IMAGE.ICON_CART_MENU}
                                resizeMode='contain'
                                style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
                            />
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: responsiveFontSize(3), padding: 10 }}>Your cart is currently empty</Text>
                            <Button info onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Feed')}><Text> Return To Shop </Text></Button>
                        </View>
                        :
                        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', margin: 5 }}>
                            <View style={styles.maindiv}>
                                
                                    <FlatList
                                        data={this.state.productlist}
                                        renderItem={this.renderCategory}
                                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                    />
                                


                            </View>

                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkout()}>
                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#473e59', height: 44, width: responsiveWidth(92), margin: 10 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: responsiveFontSize(1.5), color: '#fff' }}>CHECKOUT</Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <AnimatedLoader
                                visible={this.state.isLoading}
                                overlayColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.75)"
                                animationStyle={styles.lottie}
                                speed={1}
                            />

                        </View>
                }
               
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default MyCartScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#a5a2db',
    },
    maindiv: {
        height: responsiveHeight(68),

    },
    childdiv: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height: responsiveHeight(17.9),
        backgroundColor: '#eef3f7',
        margin: 5,
        borderRadius: 6
    },
    TextInput: {
        height: responsiveHeight(7),
        width: responsiveWidth(60),
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2),
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderColor: '#eaeaea',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginTop: 10
    },
    moreImg: {
        height: responsiveHeight(16),
        width: responsiveWidth(28),
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        margin: 5,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
    navItemStyle: {
        margin: 5
    },
    price: {
        marginTop: 10,
        color: 'red'
    },
    lottie: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }

});
```

this is my component which I want to update from this screen.
when this screen will be open. custom header automatically will be updated, but now custom header holds previous data.

Comment: You might need [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this.

Comment: have any other way?

Comment: If you're building a `production` level app, you're more or less required to use `context`. You have to look into it some day if you're doing react.